# How do I import telegrams source code from github

Tags: android, android-studio, telegram

How do  I import telegram source code from GitHub and I tried to import it and my android studio just got stuck on building the source code

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.

Note: If the repository is empty, you can manually copy the repository page's URL from your browser and skip to step four.

Clone or download buttonUnder the repository name, click Clone or download.
Clone URL buttonIn the Clone with HTTPs section, click  to copy the clone URL for the repository.

Open Terminal.

Change the current working directory to the location where you want the cloned directory to be made.

Type git clone, and then paste the URL you copied in Step 2.

git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
Press Enter. Your local clone will be created.

git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
Cloning into `Spoon-Knife`...
remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remove: Total 10 (delta 1), reused 10 (delta 1)
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.

[Readmore](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/)